# Dummy interface in an LXC guest

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, network-adapter, container

I am trying to create a split-horizon PPTP setup as [described on my website](http://www.janoszen.com/2012/08/07/in-search-of-the-perfect-vpn-solution/) within an LXC container. However, I need a **dummy interface within the container** to put the DHCP server on.

Here comes the problem: within the container I can't run `modprobe dummy` to create my dummy interface. (Technically I can if I have the kernel modules installed, but it won't do anything.)

The container itself is a host to more containers, so I'm using the apparmor profile from [Stéphane Graber](https://www.stgraber.org/2012/05/04/lxc-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/). The operating system on both the host and the guest is a stock Ubuntu 12.04 with all upgrades applied to date.

Questions:

- Is there a way to configure the dummy module in any other way besides modprobe?
- Is it possible to use the dummy module in an LXC guest?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround in the official documentation, however I'm not very satisfied with it. You can use the network type `phys` to pair up a network interface with a dummy interface on the host side;

```
 lxc.network.type = phys
 lxc.network.flags = up
 lxc.network.link = dummy0
 lxc.network.hwaddr = 4a:49:43:49:79:ff
 lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.2.3.6/24
 lxc.network.ipv6 = 2003:db8:1:0:214:1234:fe0b:3297
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following configuration, which should be slightly safer:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.name = dummy0
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.hwaddr = xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

I then configure the interface from within the LXC container itself.